# jquery in tumblr theme won't work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to put jquery into a tumblr theme but for some reason it won't work. I've looked at a ton of similar questions and found this bit of code from a tutorial about jquery in tumblr themes

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.3");
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    jQuery(function($) {
      // do some stuff here, eg load your tweets, ...
    });
  });
</script>
```

And this is what the finished jquery part of my theme looks like. It's intended to make an infinite down and up scroll (or at least the illusion of one) but it won't work in the theme.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "2.0.2");
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    jQuery(function($) {
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var html = $(".what").html();
            var what = '<div class="what">'+html+'</div>';
            $(window).scrollTop(1);
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
                    $(".what").last().after(what);
                    if ($(".what").length > 2) {
                        $(".what").last().prev().remove();
                        $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - $(".what").first().height());
                    }
                }
                else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
                    $(".what").first().before(what);
                    $(window).scrollTop($(".what").first().height());
                    if ($(".what").length > 2) {
                        $(".what").last().remove();
                    }
                }    
            });
        }); 
    })( jQuery );

    });
  });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: `"but for some reason it won't work"` isn't a good explanation at all of the issue. Check your console for errors. Are there any? etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a copy / paste error. There is an unclosed `script` tag, and using the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript, without including the actually library.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var html = $(".what").html();
        var what = '<div class="what">'+html+'</div>';
        $(window).scrollTop(1);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
                $(".what").last().after(what);
                if ($(".what").length > 2) {
                    $(".what").last().prev().remove();
                    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - $(".what").first().height());
                }
            }
            else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
                $(".what").first().before(what);
                $(window).scrollTop($(".what").first().height());
                if ($(".what").length > 2) {
                    $(".what").last().remove();
                }
            }    
        });
    }); 
</script>
```